# Vorpal very long parameter gets cut

Tags: javascript, vorpal.js

I've created a Vorpal command:

```
vorpal.command('getURL <url>')
```

The problem is when i pass a very long URL it gets cut. I believe there is some restriction on the length of the parameter. Is there any workaround? Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
// getUrl "www.example.com/?test=rest"
vorpal
.command('getUrl <url>')
.action(function (arg, callback) {
    console.log(arg.url);
    callback();
});
```

this logs only www.example.com/?

Comment: Can you help narrow down on how many characters it cuts after? And does this change based on how wide you console window is?

Comment: I tried this with 1700 characters and it printed out properly. Please clarify with a little more information on how to reproduce this.

Comment: @dthree ups, i was wrong, url gets cut after the question mark, so for instance when passing this url http://www.example.com/?test=rest  i get only http://www.example.com/?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Vorpal. I tried this with a question mark, and it was fine as well. Log the output from Vorpal before you use it. Likely something else is dropping the question mark after Vorpal hands it off.

Comment: did you test i with the example string i wrote before? because it cuts only if question mark is followed with x=y i.e ?something=anothersomething, but if you just put random string without equal sign it works.

Comment: @dthree forgot to mention you in the comment.

Comment: Okay try wrapping the URL value in "quotes". Does this change the result?

Comment: @dthree  it didn't help, when adding optional arg to next to the url, i can get the url parameter from that optional arg: `vorpal.command('getURL <url> [test])` passing `getURL www.example.com?abc=rest` ; the `abc=rest` is in the `test` arg, however it adds single quotes to the `rest`.

Comment: Okay, but what occurs when you do `getURL "www.example.com?abc=rest"`?

Comment: @dthree updated the question

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
vorpal.isCommandArgKeyPairNormalized = false
```

More info: https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/issues/130